# Why is Slidey back? Or, live notifications are broken, at least for me

Tags: bug, status-norepro, notifications, notification-bar

I've noticed some other evidence that the devs are working on the site:

[My iPad started showing the mobile version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144693/my-ipad-started-showing-the-mobile-version)

And I've noticed (as have others) that the site is no longer doing real-time updates:

[Stack Overflow is not getting refreshed automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/stackoverflow-com-is-not-getting-refreshed-automatically)

Perhaps these are unrelated, but I'm also wondering why I'm now seeing the orange slidey at the top of the window over the past few days, instead of the newer streamlined notification bars:

[image]

I'm seeing this in multiple browsers and multiple operating systems. Right now I am seeing this on Chrome 21 and Firefox 15 on Mac OS X, but I have also seen it on Win8 + IE10. I see this on dba.stackexchange as well, so it's not isolated to SO. I've also noticed that in all browsers my reputation has stopped being live updated (this occurs in all sites, including meta).

Some other evidence of not quite right behavior, even here on meta. Two different browser windows on the same page, with differing information. The telling part is that some info is newer in one window, while other info is newer in the other.

[image]

I've also noticed that, across all sites I frequent on the network:

1. On question pages, new comments (or edits to comments, or up-votes on comments) don't appear/update until I refresh
2. On question pages, edits to posts no longer trigger a notification bar (this means I don't always notice that a post has been updated unless I manually check the timestamp)
3. On question pages, up-vote and favorite counts are not updated until I refresh
4. On tag/home pages, new questions do not appear (no banner) until I refresh

The only difference on my end, that seems to coincide with the change in behavior, is that I am on the West Coast this week, primarily using hotel WiFi. Perhaps there is some algorithm in place that detects that my bandwidth sucks, and reverts me to the old, you-must-refresh-constantly behavior? Perhaps this is all just a bad dream and the proper behavior will revert when I'm back in my own time zone?

Comment: Hmm, odd that it's not happening here on Meta when Meta is the one people are complaining about with the iPad issue. :/ The devs should learn to break *one* thing at a time.

Comment: @animuson are you saying that you see this behavior on the main site, but not on meta? Or do you not see any of the behavior I'm describing on any site?

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to reproduce this issue - I have restarted all of our web socket servers to see if this helped.  Let me know if you're still seeing an issue.

Comment: No, live refresh is still not working for me anywhere, and on the main site I'm still able to manifest Slidey. This just happened to me two minutes ago: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HFlfr.png

Comment: @AaronBertrand after looking at the logs it appears you are using a Mac on Firefox 15?  As a rule we don't support early release browsers since there is probably a bug that we have no control over.  Did this stop working for you recently?

Comment: Yes, it stopped working for me less than a week ago. It also stopped working for me on Chrome.

Comment: Was there any change in your network config?  I see requests being made to our socket servers from you.  I am noticing your using HTTP 1.0 instead of 1.1 - is it possible to send us a network trace from fiddler at team@stackexchange.com

Comment: Delay that - I may have found an issue on our end.

Comment: Yes, there was a change. `The only difference on my end, that seems to coincide with the change in behavior, is that I am on the West Coast this week, primarily using hotel WiFi.`

Comment: PS thanks for your persistence in looking into this.

Comment: Ok, I have made a change to the socket server and deployed again.  One thing to note - hotel wireless generally routes their traffic through notoriously crappy proxy servers that usually receive no updates.  Web socket technology is somewhat new so I doubt it would be working.  If it fails it would fail for all web sites that use sockets for realtime features, you can check your support here:  http://websocketstest.com/

Comment: Thanks, looks like I've got everything but WebSockets support on 80/8080: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9LbIG.png Guess I'll just have to live with it until I return home. Is Slidey implemented intentionally when WebSockets are not supported, or is that perhaps a different issue than the lack of live refresh (for now obvious reasons)?

Comment: Yes, slidey is our fallback to notifying of new answers when web sockets are not working.  I'll see if I can get a build that will use port 443.  We have seen better results using this port.