# I'm not getting notifications on new comments and answers

Tags: bug, notifications

Its a while that I'm **not** informed by those notification bars (or anything else!) when:

- I'm pinged (@4r1y4n).
- I get an answer for my question
- I get new comment to my question
- I get new comment to my answer
- I get new badge

and in a word I don't see any notifications!
live refresh (notifications about edit and new answers when I'm in the question) works well for me! just I don't see notifications about questions that I was active in them (e.g. questions, answers or comments) when I open other pages.

What is the problem?

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is Slidey back?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144698/why-is-slidey-back)

Comment: @animuson: I don't think so! I'm not seeing anything and he is seeing something!

Comment: If live refresh isn't working, it's probably related to notifications not working. I'm merely saying they're probably related.

Comment: @animuson: live refresh (notifications about edit and new answers when I'm in the question) works well for me! just I don't see notifications about questions that I was active in them (mine or others) when I open other pages. but may be related. i don't know!