# stackoverflow.com/questions is not updating

Tags: bug, questions, live-refresh, updating-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow is not getting refreshed automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/stack-overflow-is-not-getting-refreshed-automatically)

Every time I open stackoverflow.com and [click on the "questions" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), the page doesn't update with new questions. Why?

Comment: It is updating just fine for me.

Comment: You do not have it ordered by votes, unanswered or similar instead of newest...right?!

Comment: @JoshMein can you check it once? It will not update..

Comment: Just looking at the SO questions list shows 7 questions posted in the last minute - if it was live it would probably scroll past too quicky to be useful.

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary If you are referring to auto-updating you should be more specific.

Comment: @JoshMein I'm trying to be more specific, New bee..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main Stack Overflow pages do not use live-updating; it would be too much of a performance penalty on the server due to the high volume of questions.